# How do I display navigation on button press with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page on which I display an icon to show the menu when the width of the page is = or < 900 pixels. For now, I just set the navigation `display:none;` but I'm wondering how I go about displaying it `inline` when someone clicks on the button. See my page is at http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/ (minimize the size to < 900 pixels, and you'll see the nav button).

Answer (score 1):

This name is [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). You can use jQuery plugins like [slicknav](http://slicknav.com/).

Comment: I used the toggle propert from jquery instead, works quite nicely! I'd rather learn it myself than use some third party modules... but thanks for your comment anyways, <upvote>

Answer (score 0):

I used the toggle propert from jQuery instead, and it works quite nicely! I'd rather learn it myself than use some third-party modules:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showbutton").click(function(){
            $("#navigation").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```